# How to know if widget is in focus?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a music widget which controls the native music player. It shows the clip art and other song info to the user. But I don't want my widget to update when user does not have focus on the widget, in other words I don't want widget to react to the intents it receives if user is not playing with widget and it is not in focus. So, I am curious to know if there is a way to know a widget or particular page of the home screen is in focus. I have seen this working on HTC sense's clock widget - it updates the time only when the focus to the widget is active.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Regards,
SKU